# How to add a 0/1 indicator's column into SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to set `IsDriver` to 1 if a user is listed in table `rides`. Otherwise `IsDriver` should be 0.

```
SELECT rides.IdRide, users.IdUser, IsDriver
FROM users, rides
LEFT JOIN...
WHERE rides.IdUser = users.IdUser
```

Sample output:

```
idRide | idUser | ISDriver
1      | 1      | 0
1      | 2      | 1
2      | 1      | 1
3      | 3      | 1
```

Comment: Put a CASE in the select list.

Comment: BTW, don't mix old style implicit join syntax with modern explicit join...

Comment: @jarlh: Could you please give an example in the answer?

Comment: Show us the two table definitions, and also some sample data.

Comment: @jarlh: What do you mean by old style implicit join syntax? Do you suggest to avoid using LEFT JOIN?

Comment: The opposite, JOIN (and LEFT JOIN) is new style explicit join syntax! Avoid the old "table, table" syntax.

Comment: No,  left join is OK. An implicit join with just a comma should be avoided.

Comment: how do you distinguish a passenger from a driver? are they both in the table rides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to :

```
SELECT users.IdUser, (rides.IdUser is not null) as IsDriver, rides.IdRide
FROM users
LEFT JOIN rides ON rides.IdUser = users.IdUser
```

It looks like your sample output is incorrect. The first row must have IdRide = null, because there is no corresponding line in the rides table.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT r.IdRide, u.IdUser,
(CASE WHEN  r.IdRide IS NOT NULL THEN 1
     ELSE 0
END
)As IsDriver

FROM users u
LEFT JOIN rides r ON  
u.IdUser =r.IdUser
```

Comment: Use table alias everywhere if defined. (r.IdRide etc).